# 2 actions when a hyper link is clicked

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink named "LogOut". Once I click the link, getting the confirmation from the user using 'confirm' and redirecting to logout.jsp.

After getting confirmation as Yes, is it possible call a function before submitting the form?

Code snippet:

```
<P align=right> 
    <a href='logout.jsp' 
       onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to logout now?')">LogOut</a>
</P>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap *all* the actions you want to take into a single function, and call that.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function Logout()
        {
            if (confirm('Do you really want to logout now?'))
            {
                return SomeOtherFunction();
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function SomeOtherFunction()
        {
            return true;
        } 
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <P align=right> 
        <a href='logout.jsp' 
           onclick="return Logout()">LogOut</a>
    </P>
</body>
```